# Неявное связывание DLL с одинаковыми именами функций

Tags: c++, c

Есть несколько dll, в которых встречаются функции с одинаковыми именами (т. е. когда сразу в нескольких dll есть функция с таким именем). Есть ли какой-нибудь способ указать компилятору (линковщику) для каждой из этих функций конкретную dll, из которой она должна вызываться? Желательно, не изменяя файлов `*.lib`.

P.S. - `LoadLibrary`/`GetProcAddress` не предлагать, интересует именно неявное связывание, через таблицу импорта.

Comment: В c++ нет понятия dll. Какой header подключите, с такой функйие и будете работать. Либо вручную присваивать указатели на функции с помощью платформо-зависимого кода.

Comment: Мне кажется, что у это проблема XY. Конфликты имен или отсутствие версионности - это дефекты.